# How to make a selection that converts some portion of the image into sketch through the action in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

Ok I want to create an action in Photoshop that will be applicable on the area which is selected. I want to apply the effect of the action on some part of the image. For that, I saw some where that before clicking on play button to play the action, need to select the portion on which u want to apply effect.

I want to know how does that action made? [image]

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to Vectorize and Image ?

Comment: No, want to make action as shown in above image

Comment: oh so youre not talking about the sketch-app ?? The images are from a Sevenstyles Action. They require you to make a layer called "brush" the action uses that layer qs mask etc

Comment: No.. I am am not talking about app..I want to create exactly the same action  as they have created..So wanted to learn how they have created that action

Comment: I have that kind of brushes, patterns and method but cant understand how It is possible to create that action which will be applicable on particular portion of the image

Comment: I got answer of my question own my own and super happy with the result!!

Comment: yeah sure I'll post it very soon but yeah this is  actually what I was looking for..I have created sketch action

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic since it's a request for support on a custom script created by a third party.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please post it here and m ark is as the accepted answer. I am very, *very* skeptical about achieving this effect with just an action. To me it looks like this would take multiple hours of professional image editing to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In your action create a new layer with the name "Selection".

Pause there and ask for the user paint the areas they'd like to convert.

Then once the layer has been painted on resume the action and create a step that selects the pixels of the "Selection" layer (right click on the layer preview > select pixels).

Then go on with your action. This way when you play back your action, a new layer will be created, the user will paint the selection, then the action can use that painted area to create the selection.

I will try to edit this later with a bit more step by step info, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.